# Create a single img from tiled img

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, html5-canvas

How can I create a single image from a tiled structure like this:

```
+-----+-----+-----+
|tile1|tile2|tile3|
+-----+-----+-----+

<div>        
  <div>    
    <img> tile 1
  </div>  
</div>
<div>        
  <div>    
    <img> tile 2
  </div>  
</div>
<div>        
  <div>    
    <img>  tile 3
  </div>  
</div>
```

This is the detail:

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: -256px; top: -256px; width: 256px; height: 256px;">
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
         <img src="tile1.png" style="width: 256px; height: 256px;">
    </div>
</div>
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: -256px; width: 256px; height: 256px;">
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
         <img src="tile2.png" style="width: 256px; height: 256px;">
    </div>
</div>
....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply make a canvas big enough to hold all of your images, then draw each image at the appropriate offset to replicate the same tiling effect that your HTML provides.

Or, if you really want to specifically capture the layout from your HTML, there's a package called html2canvas (https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) which will do screen captures from any HTML, not just tiled images.